# Axibase startime and endtime not working

Tags: time-series, timeserieschart, axibase

Trying to make a portal that only shows 20 min of an outage time.  Can't get startime to work.  Tried 2 different formats.  Always starting from Jan 1 1970.  Please advise.

```
[configuration]
 title = ECP_PROD_PEAKVIEW
    width-units = 6
    height-units = 8
    offset-right = 50
    update-interval = 15
     display-date = true
    startime = 2017-12-21 09:20:00
    endtime = 2017-12-21 09:45:00
    auto-scale = true
    auto-period = true
   entity = dnvrco-ecp01
    endtime = now 
        alert-style = fill: red; stroke: red


and 

[configuration]
 title = ECP_PROD_PEAKVIEW
    width-units = 6
    height-units = 8
    offset-right = 50
    update-interval = 15
     display-date = true
     startime = 2017-12-21T09:20:00Z
     endtime = 2017-12-21T09:45:00Z
     auto-scale = true
    auto-period = true
   entity = dnvrco-ecp01
    endtime = now 
    alert-style = fill: red; stroke: red
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `startime` setting is missing a `t`.

```
  starttime = 2017-12-21 09:20:00
```

You can add dash symbols to make parameters more reedable:

```
  start-time = 2017-12-21 09:20:00
  end-time = 2017-12-21 09:45:00
```

Example: https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/47fbef76

I would also remove the duplicate `endtime` setting in the `[configuration]` section.

In case you need to show the most recent 20 minutes, just specify the `timespan` and remove `start-time` and `end-time` altogether.

Both `start-time` and `end-time` settings accept [calendar expressions](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/end-time/).

```
  start-time = previous_hour
  end-time = current_hour
```

Or, alternatively:

```
  timespan = 1 hour
  end-time = current_hour
```